# Set style to a range where there are merged cells C# excel

Tags: c#, excel, styles

I have this line:

```
excelObject.workSheet.Range["A" + index + ":AA" + index].Style = "Found";
```

And

```
Excel.Style oStyle;
oStyle = excelObject.application.ActiveWorkbook.Styles.Add("Found");
oStyle.Font.Bold = true;
oStyle.Interior.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Green);
```

But when it try to set the style in a range which has merged cells it throws an error of: "We can't do that to a merged cell."

but if I try the same code in VBA it works:
[VBA example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IFzz6.png)

So is there a way to do that in C#

Comment: I question if this would would work using VBA. I tried your code in the picture using VBA and I got the same error. So I question your statement _I try the same code in VBA it works_ . Unfortunately I don't think you can do this unless you un-merge the cells first.

Comment: @JohnG , I did the test in VBA again and it still works, I don't know if it's the way I merge the cells but there isn't any error.
I decided to unmerge the cells and write the data  where the cells lose their values.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

```
try
{
    excelObject.workSheet.Range["A" + index + ":AA" + index].Style = "Found";
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    if (ex.Message.Equals("We can't do that to a merged cell."))
    {
        /*
            1 means A 
            27 means AA
            index is the current row
        */
        if (!setStyleInNoMergedCells(1, 27, index, "Found"))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Fail);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Fail);
    }
}

private Boolean setStyleInNoMergedCells(int startRange,int endRange, int row,String styleString)
{
    for (int i = startRange; i <= endRange; i++)
    {
        try
        {
            Excel.Range rng = (Excel.Range) excelMDB.workSheet.Cells[row, i];
            if (rng.MergeCells)
            {
                Excel.Range rngMerged = rng.MergeArea;
                Excel.Range rngStart = rngMerged.Cells[1, 1];
                string value = rngStart.Value;
                rng.UnMerge();

                foreach (Excel.Range cell in rngMerged)
                {
                    cell.Value = value;
                }

                rng.Style = styleString;
            }
            else
            {
                rng.Style = styleString;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Console.Write("[setStyleInNoMergedCells] error:\r\n" + ex.Message);
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```